# With "reject_sender_login_mismatch" I can no longer send email

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I've added "reject_sender_login_mismatch" to "**smtpd_sender_restrictions**" as was suggested to me. Now I get this when sending an email:

```
    <my_email@my_domain.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user my_email@my_domain.com
```

The logs of postfix:

```
  localhost postfix/submission/smtpd[26211]: connect from unknown[11.22.33.44]
  localhost postfix/submission/smtpd[26211]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[11.22.33.44]: 553 5.7.1 <my_email@my_domain.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user my_email@my_domain.com; from=<my_email@my_domain.com> to=<some_external_email@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[66.77.88.99]>
  localhost postfix/submission/smtpd[26211]: disconnect from unknown[11.22.33.44] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 quit=1 commands=6/7
```

**Note that all does work when I comment out "reject_sender_login_mismatch"** 
Why doesn't it work with it? How to fix **this**?

Here's a part of my postfix config:

```
  virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
  smtpd_sender_login_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
```

In the logs I also have this:

```
  localhost postfix[26246]: /usr/bin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtp_sender_login_maps=pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
```

Also note that my IP is'nt static because I carry my laptop with me everywhere.

Comment: You probably meant to use `smtpd_sender_login_maps` rather than `smtp_sender_login_maps`

Comment: @TorinCarey -- typo. The question remains